# Фильтрация блоков JSON в python

Tags: python, json

Задача отбросить лишние блоки из JSON в название которых начинается с *spring** или *managment**
Изначально приходит :

```
{
    "spring.jpa......": {
        "name": "Ford Prefect",
        "species": "Betelgeusian",
        "relatives": [
            {
                "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                "species": "Betelgeusian"
            }
        ]
    }
    "managment.endpoint......": {
        "name": "Ford Prefect",
        "species": "Betelgeusian",
        "relatives": [
            {
                "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                "species": "Betelgeusian"
            }
        ]
    }
    "searchPropirties.....": {
        "name": "Ford Prefect",
        "species": "Betelgeusian",
        "relatives": [
            {
                "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                "species": "Betelgeusian"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

И таких блоков может быть много.
после обработки должен остаться только:

```
   {
        "searchPropirties.....": {
            "name": "Ford Prefect",
            "species": "Betelgeusian",
            "relatives": [
                {
                    "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                    "species": "Betelgeusian"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Возможно ли это сделать на Python для такого запроса?

```
 curl <ip>/actuator/configprops |
    python -c "import sys, json, re; \
    obj = json.load(sys.stdin)['contexts']['search']['beans']; \
    print json.dumps(obj);"  |
    python -m json.tool | less
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from json import loads

formatted = {}

for key in loads(sys.stdin):
    if not key.startswith('spring') and not key.starswith('managment'):
        formatted[key] = sys.stdin[key]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]